# Subsetting data in datatable in R using i with paste command

Tags: r, data.table

I have following datatable DT1 which has yearly values:

```
        Var1        Var2
NORM_FACTOR_2014    1.026
NORM_FACTOR_2015    0.781
```

I want to get Var2 value based on the year I pass as year parameter in my script. So say, if I am running for Year=2014 then I should obviously get Var2 = 1.026 stored in my variable. For this I am trying to use paste function but its not working. Here is what I am trying:

> DF  <- DT1[Var1 == get(paste0("NORM_FACTOR_",Year)), Var2]

```
 Error in get(paste0("NORM_FACTOR_", Year)) : 
 object 'NORM_FACTOR_2014' not found
```

But when I am doing just this:

> DF  <- DT1[Var1 == "NORM_FACTOR_2014",Var2]
>
> DF
>       [1] 1.026

I am getting value. I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Solution: I got this solution, so it's working without get function:

> DF  <- DT1[Var1 == paste0("NORM_FACTOR_",Batch_Year),Var2]

I do't know why I was using get() anyways.

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extract year from `Var1` using `gsub`?

Comment: Actually I am using Year for so many things in script and regulates my other crosswalks as well. But actually its working without get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to do this:

```
DF <- DT1[DT1$Var1 == paste0("NORM_FACTOR_", Year), "Var2"]
```

I use `DT1$Var1` and "Var2" instead of just `Var1` because I'm not assuming any previous use of `attach(DT1)`.

**Edit**:

Alternative:

```
DF <- DT1$Var2[DT1$Var1 == paste0("NORM_FACTOR_", Year)]
```

And using regular expressions:

```
DF <- DT1$Var2[grep(Year, DT1$Var1)]
```

Comment: You are treating a data.table like a data.frame. Technically it inherits that class, but this is still very inefficient. However, this question seems to suffer from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) which makes it difficult to give good advice.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
extract<-DT1[substr(Var1,13,16)==Year,Var2]
```

This is basically what @Marat Talipov suggested, which is more like

```
DT1[,yr:=substr(Var1,13,16)]
extract<-DT1[yr==Year,Var2]
```